# Conditionally add scrollView for smaller screens

Tags: javascript, react-native

When using an `overlay` in my app, how Can I add a `ScrollView` for smaller devices?

First I am checking for the width:

```
const windowWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
```

Then I am trying to render the ScrollView:

```
{!loading && (
      
        // Add start tag
        { windowWidth = 320 && <ScrollView> }

        <Text
          ...
        >
          {modalBody}
        </Text>

        // Add end tag
        { windowWidth = 320 && </ScrollView> }
        
      )}
```

Amy ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this like,

```
const ViewTag = windowWidth === 320 ? ScrollView : View;

{!loading && (
      
        <ViewTag>

          <Text
            ...
          >
           {modalBody}
          </Text>

        </ViewTag>
        
      )}
```